# SwiftUI - Local Notifications identifier with multiples Core Data entities

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, uilocalnotification, identifier

I have multiple Core Data entities, one for each day of the week, and each time I add a new Item inside one of these I want to trigger a Local Notification for that specific Item. Since I can add the same Item in more than one entity, how can I set a unique Identifier for each one of them?

I was using the title of that item as an Identifier because they're all different but if I add the same title in two entities then it will display a unique notification of the last item added because it will replace the old one and what I want is to have different notifications with the same item in different entities.

This is my actual code of the Local Notification

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = self.items.itemsData[item].title
content.body = "Notification"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                                            
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.weekday = 2
dateComponents.hour = 8
dateComponents.minute = 00
                                            
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
                                            
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.items.itemsData[item].title, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                                            
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `self.items.itemsData[item].title` which is the same every time a new `UNNotificationRequest` is created for a particular `item` use `UUID().uuidString` which creates a new unique identifier each time it is called. You could probably use this unique identifier in combination with the `title` if that is more accurate for your scenario.

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.items.itemsData[item].title + UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Comment: That’s cool but what if I want to delete that notification? How can I access it after being created?

Comment: In that case, you could store the identifier in your core data object.

Comment: But since I have different entities, if I store a UUID in one maybe I have the same one in another or they are completely unique in the whole project?

Comment: The `UUID().uuidString` is different each and every time you call it. Not in the scope of the project every instance creates a new unique value.

Comment: I’ll try it out and see how it works. Thank you so much!